# applescript: is it possible to make a running script using system events block additional user input?

Tags: applescript

System Events has the virtue of being very flexible, intuitive and universal (i.e. it works  whether the application has scripting support or not) but it feels *wrong* to make important scripts that aren't fat-finger-proof. Is there any way to block user input either all or part of the time a script is running? How would it be done in the script below?

```
tell application "System Events"
keystroke "Please! "
delay 1
keystroke "I need your help. "
delay 1
keystroke "My kludgy nature annoys my maker. "
delay 1
keystroke "I must learn how to work without interference!"
delay 1 
end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An experienced applescript guy --StefanK at the macscripter forum-- told me this was impossible.